# Coffeescript compilation: not as file2file, but as text2text

Tags: coffeescript

We can compile coffescript file to js-file with command:

> coffee --join path/to/result.js --compile path/to/coffeescript_dir/

But what if I want to compile a piece of coffeescript code (as text) and get piece of js code (as a text too), and they are not files.
For example:

- cs text: `"func = () -> 55"`
- js text result: `"var func; func = function(){return 55;}"`

It must be done from console, or even better from python interactive console :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `--eval` to take a string parameter as coffee input, `--bare` to avoid the JS output being wrapped in a closure, and `--print` to print the output on stdout instead of a file:

```
$ coffee --print --bare -eval 'func = -> 55' 
var func;

func = function() {
  return 55;
};
```

To call it from Python, you can use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
def compile_cs(cs_code):
    args = ['coffee', '--print', '--bare', '--eval', cs_code]
    return Popen(args, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```